# Extjs 5 reference grid by docked button's click event without using .up?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, coding-style

I currently have a grid with a button that I click to act upon the records in the grid.  At the moment I use a `button.up('selector');` to get the grid, but it feels a bit hacky. I thought that maybe by altering the click event selector to be the `grid [action=buttonAction]` rather than just `[action=buttonAction]` might give me the context of the grid, but it doesn't. Is there any cleaner way to reference the grid rather than `button.up`?

```
var dockedItems = new Ext.toolbar.Toolbar({
                    items: {
        text: 'Do a thing',
        action: 'actionForTheThing'
    }
            });

 Ext.grid.Panel({
                store: this.store,
                dockedItems: dockedItems,
 });
```

Then in an `Ext.app.Controller` controller I define a handler

```
        this.control({
        '[action=actionForTheThing]': {
            click: this.handleTheThing
        },

       handleTheThing: function(button, click){
          //Here I have the button, but I want to get to the grid that has the button
          // Right now I can do button.up(''), but I want more of a strict relationship
          //like button.getParent(); or something.
       };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

The click event of a button is always fired with the button as the first parameter, and to change that, you would have to create an override on buttons, overriding the `fireHandler` method, where the `click` event is fired:

```
me.fireEvent('click', me, e)
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/Button.js.html#line1643

Comment: there's always the scope config which could be set to the grid (assuming you have the grid available as a var) http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.Button.html#cfg-scope